# Click on Windows Dekstop from Javascript code

Tags: javascript, windows

Is there any way to click or open programs on my Windows Dekstop from javascript code?
Actually I want to develop a screen share application where users can share and access to another user screen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But it is not easy. I can point you in the right direction. But it will take you a lot of work to get up and running. The tech you should look into is WebRTC. Read the following links.

https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/Pluginfree-Screen-Sharing/#9205741565475142

https://webrtc.org/getting-started/media-capture-and-constraints

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/